# Detecting a recurrent values and affect that value into other array

Tags: php, arrays

I am working with a one dimensional array in PHP. I would like to detect the presence of duplicate values, and affect it to another array for example this is my array:

```
$Array='piece 1','piece 1','piece 2','piece 2','piece 1','piece 1','piece 2','piece 2','piece 3','piece 3','piece 3'}
```

and this is what i want to have

```
$Arrayafter:{'piece1','piece2','piece1','piece2','piece3'}
```

How can I proceed?

Comment: `$arrayafter= array_unique($Arrray)`

Comment: ive tried this actually but it gives me $Arrayafter:{'piece1','piece2''piece3'} and what i need is $Arrayafter:{'piece1','piece2','piece1','piece2','piece3'} i want to detect the doubles but if it comes back i want to store it too

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this...

```
$newarray = array();
$lastvalue = "";

foreach ($Array as $value) {
    if ($value != $lastvalue) {
        $newarray[] = $value;
        $lastvalue = $value;
    }
}
```

I hope it helps